# How can I sync Mac Calendar with my own server?

Tags: macos, calendar, webserver

How can I sync Mac Calendar with my own server? Not one of Google, not one of Apple, iCloud. But my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch **System Preferences**
2. Select **Internet Accounts**
3. Select **Add Other Account…**
4. Select **CalDAV account**

You can then configure the calendar to synchronise with. The calendar must support CalDAV to work with macOS.

[image: Internet Accounts showing CalDAV option on macOS]